# undefined method `reply_mailboxer_conversation_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

When I attempt to render this view:

```
Reply:
<%= form_for :message, url: [:reply, conversation] do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :body %>
<%= f.submit "Send Message", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<%= submit_tag 'Clear Reply Box', type: :reset, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
<% end %>
```

I get the error: `undefined method 'reply_mailboxer_conversation_path'`

Routes:

```
 resources :messages do
  member do
      post :new
  end
end
resources :conversations do
  member do
      post :reply
      post :trash
      post :untrash
  end
  collection do
      get :trashbin
      post :empty_trash
  end
end
```

rake routes output:

```
         user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)             devise/sessions#create
 destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)            devise/sessions#destroy
        user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#create
    new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)        devise/passwords#new
   edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)       devise/passwords#edit
                      PATCH  /users/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#update
                      PUT    /users/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#update
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)              registrations#cancel
    user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                     registrations#create
 new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)             registrations#new
 edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                registrations#edit
                      PATCH  /users(.:format)                     registrations#update
                      PUT    /users(.:format)                     registrations#update
                      DELETE /users(.:format)                     registrations#destroy
                users GET    /users(.:format)                     users#index
                      POST   /users(.:format)                     users#create
             new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                 users#new
            edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)            users#edit
                 user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                 users#show
                      PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                 users#update
                      PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                 users#update
                      DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                 users#destroy
                 root GET    /                                    profiles#index
              message POST   /messages/:id(.:format)              messages#new
             messages GET    /messages(.:format)                  messages#index
                      POST   /messages(.:format)                  messages#create
          new_message GET    /messages/new(.:format)              messages#new
         edit_message GET    /messages/:id/edit(.:format)         messages#edit
                      GET    /messages/:id(.:format)              messages#show
                      PATCH  /messages/:id(.:format)              messages#update
                      PUT    /messages/:id(.:format)              messages#update
                      DELETE /messages/:id(.:format)              messages#destroy
   reply_conversation POST   /conversations/:id/reply(.:format)   conversations#reply
   trash_conversation POST   /conversations/:id/trash(.:format)   conversations#trash
 untrash_conversation POST   /conversations/:id/untrash(.:format) conversations#untrash
trashbin_conversations GET    /conversations/trashbin(.:format)    conversations#trashbin
empty_trash_conversations POST   /conversations/empty_trash(.:format) conversations#empty_trash
        conversations GET    /conversations(.:format)             conversations#index
                      POST   /conversations(.:format)             conversations#create
     new_conversation GET    /conversations/new(.:format)         conversations#new
    edit_conversation GET    /conversations/:id/edit(.:format)    conversations#edit
         conversation GET    /conversations/:id(.:format)         conversations#show
                      PATCH  /conversations/:id(.:format)         conversations#update
                      PUT    /conversations/:id(.:format)         conversations#update
                      DELETE /conversations/:id(.:format)         conversations#destroy
```

Really not sure what I'm doing wrong. If I've left out any important code, please just let me know.

https://github.com/portOdin/gfi2/tree/june6/app/views

Comment: can you paste your rake routes from the rails console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're receiving is because of how you're defining your `form_for` block:

```
<%= form_for :message, url: [:reply, conversation] do |f| %>
```

---

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for):

> **Resource-oriented style**
>
> In the examples just shown, although not indicated explicitly, we
>   still need to use the :url option in order to specify where the form
>   is going to be sent. However, further simplification is possible if
>   the record passed to form_for is a resource, i.e. it corresponds to a
>   set of RESTful routes, e.g. defined using the resources method in
>   config/routes.rb. In this case Rails will simply infer the appropriate
>   URL from the record itself. For example,

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

> is then equivalent to something like:

```
<%= form_for @post, as: :post, url: post_path(@post), method: :patch, html: { class: "edit_post", id: "edit_post_45" } do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

--

**Nested**

When you use an array for the `resource` part of `form_for`, you're basically telling rails that `conversation` will inherit from `reply`.

We use it like this:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @object] do |f| %>
```

This basically treats the `url` attribute like this:

url: reply_conversation_path

I don't know where it got `mailboxer` from, but either way, the problem will be caused by the declaration of `[:reply, conversation]`.

--

**Fix**

There are two ways to fix this.

The first is to use the `url:` attribute inside the `form_for`, like this:

```
<%= form_for [:reply, @conversation], url: reply_conversation_path(conversation) do |f| %>
```

The second is to use the correct formatting:

```
<%= form_for @reply, url: reply_conversation_path(@conversation) do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: How are you using <%= form_for @conversation, ... %>? Don't you think it will be @reply?

Comment: You're probably right - I was mainly demonstrating the point (about the `url`). `@reply` would have to be the `ActiveRecord object` I think. The routes state: `/conversations/:id/reply`, which means you are right, as you'll have `@conversation` as the parent, with `@reply` as a new `Message`

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that you have to keep in mind whenever you make a form

a. You need to initialise your resource in your controller, in your case reply. I'm assuming you are in show action of conversations controller so you can initialise it like this:

```
@reply = Message.new   # assuming you dont have a reply model and you are using message model as reply
```

b. The path where you are creating your resource. If you look at your rake routes

**reply_conversation POST   /conversations/:id/reply(.:format)   conversations#reply**. You can clearly see that you need to have a conversation to make a reply in that conversation so again you'll have to find that conversation in your show action of conversations controller like this:

```
@conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])
```

Now to make a form is relatively simple

```
<% form_for @reply, url: reply_conversation_path(@conversation.id) do |f| %>
  <%= #your fields %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You won't be able to use the path directly in the `form_for` method - you'll need to use `url: reply_conversation_path`

Comment: @RichPeck my bad, forgot to add it